# values from model are not updating to the view

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-model, ember.js-view, ember-controllers

I have displayed a textbox using Ember.View. 
In model i had specified all the details of the input.

```
App.Display = DS.Model.extend({
inputText: DS.attr('string'),
width: DS.attr('string'),
height: DS.attr('string'),
className: DS.attr('string')
})
App.Display.FIXTURES = [{
id: '1',
innnerText : 'helo',
width: '197px',
height: '25px',
className: 'DisplayClass'
}]
```

from the model how can i append the className , width,height and innerText to the display unit.

Here is my displayView

```
 <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_display">
{{#view 'App.DisplayView'}}{{/view}}
 </script>

 App.DisplayView = Ember.View.extend({
tagName: 'input',

});

 App.DisplayController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
actions: {

}
});
```

How to populate the model data (i.e. innerText,dimensions,className)  through controller to the view.
Note:Im not using any this.resource('somename')

In IndexRoute i have set the controller

```
  setupController: function (controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    this.controllerFor('Display').set('model', model.displayInput);
```

In IndexRoute

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function(){
    return {
        //findall of model name 
        displayInput : this.store.findAll('display')
 }
 }
```

Now to use model to set and get the value of input

Comment: That looks like the default behaviour for `setupController`, do you have more logic in the method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Working demo on JS Bin.](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ramuraforu/edit?html,js,output) You're using views - deprecated feature now - instead of components, which make code look not very nice and it's not ideal tool to implement behaviour you want. Instead I converted your approach to use components. Also, in Fixtures you've defined `innnerText` instead of `inputText`.

So, let's start with component. Code:

```
App.DisplayComponentComponent = Ember.Component.extend({
   tagName: 'input',
  attributeBindings: ['style', 'value'],
  style: Ember.computed('model', 'model.{width,height}', function() {
    var ret = '',
        width = this.get('model.width'),
        height = this.get('model.height');

    if (width) {
      ret += 'width: ' + width + ';';
    }

    if (height) {
      ret += 'height: ' + height + ';';
    }

    return ret;
  })
});
```

Component template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="display-component">
</script>
```

Then, correct fixtures:

```
App.Display.FIXTURES = [{
id: '1',
inputText : 'helo',
width: '197px',
height: '25px',
className: 'DisplayClass'
}];
```

There's also a problem with your `model`. I think it'll be easier to initialize model for display controller just in `setupController` model.

```
setupController: function (controller, model) {
    controller.set('model', model);
    this.store.findAll('display').then(function(displays) {
        this.controllerFor('display').set('model', display.get('firstObject'));
    });
}
```

Then, if you want to use it, do it like that(I'm using your example with `_display` template, but I don't have a clue how do you use this):

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_display">
{{display-component model=model class=model.className value=model.inputText}}
</script>
```

I have to assume that `_display` template is for display controller, because you're question isn't clear at all.

Comment: Referring to the view as `'App.DisplayView'` instead of `'display'` was deprecated even earlier. I agree with the suggestion of using a component instead.

Comment: Thanks. But here this.get('model.width') is undefined. @Daniel

Comment: Even the className and value is not appended. How to resolve this @Daniel

Comment: views that i have used in my implementation, is it deprecated now ? I referred few tutorials which suggested me to use the Ember.View . thanks for the information. @Daniel